# How to connect to sql server from google sheet by Jdbc.getConnection

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-sheets, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to connect to sql server database in google sheet by a function.

When I use sql server management studio, I use "windows authentication" to login to the server to access database. Hence, there is no password to access database.

This is my function code:

```
function readsql() {


  var confirm = Browser.msgBox("please confirm to proceed", Browser.Buttons.YES_NO); 
  if(confirm!='yes'){return};// if user click NO then exit the function, else continue with the loading


  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MY_SERVER_NAME:1433;databaseName=mydb");

  var confirm = Browser.msgBox(conn, Browser.Buttons.YES_NO); 
  if(confirm!='yes'){return};// if user click NO then exit the function, else continue with the loading

  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [mydb] where [column_name_value] = 123");

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.create('newsheet');
  var cell = doc.getRange('A1');
  var row = 0;
  while(rs.next()) {
    cell.offset(row, 0).setValue(rs.getString(1));
    cell.offset(row, 1).setValue(rs.getString(2));
    row++;
  }
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
}
```

But, I am getting this error:

```
Connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol.
```

Comment: Note that your server is required to be accessible from the internet before Google sheet can connect to it

Comment: Hi @Ferrybig how can i access server via internet or browser? How to test this?

Comment: hi @Ferrybig I have updated my connection info and now I am getting a new error . Please refer to the updated code above. Could you please help? Not sure what this error means.

Comment: I highly doubt whether you can connect without a password, but the url should be `jdbc:sqlserver://MY_SERVER_NAME:1433/mydb`

Comment: Hi @TheMaster in my case there is no password. I login to SQL server with widows authentication. Also what this error means and how to fix it? "Connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol"

Comment: The url is of format `jdbc:subprotocol://subname/db name`. The protocol is not supported (i.e., `jtds`)

Comment: Also, You need to enable some other authentication method; AFAIK, Google doesn't support windows auth and The script runs on Google's servers not on your browser or the intranet.